# Why is Django giving me: 'first_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a custom user profile and have modified the example only slightly

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, first_name=None, last_name=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            #date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name=None, last_name=None):

        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,            
            #date_of_birth=date_of_birth
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length = 30),
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length = 30),    
    #date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

When I try to run syncdb I get the following error:

```
You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Email address: uou@pce.com
Password:
Password (again):
TypeError: 'first_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I have struggled to debug this because of the limited nature of the error message.  I feel I'm making a simple mistake what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have commas after your `first_name` and `last_name` declaration in your `MyUser` model which shouldn't be there. Is this a typo?

Comment: Django doesn't seem to be using your custom User model and/or Manager. Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set None (Null) value into first_name and it seems that this property don't allow it.

Try this changes:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, first_name='', last_name=''):
```

In model:

```
first_name=models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
```